# Mysql both querys use "Using where & Using temporary", but there is speed difference

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, where-clause, using, temporary

I have two queries for getting some information like below.

1. ```
   SELECT distinct(I), O from (SELECT I, O FROM HB WHERE ID > 0) as H;
   ```
2. ```
   SELECT distinct(I), O FROM HB WHERE ID > 0;
   ```

1. explain like below:

   ```
   1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL                 5   Using temporary
   2   DERIVED HB  range   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4       5   Using where
   ```
2. like this:

   ```
   1   SIMPLE  HB  range   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4       5   Using where; Using temporary
   ```

It has some difference but I guess using where and temporary. So It'll have to same result.

But 1. is very slower than 2. What makes this difference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `select distinct` is **NOT** a function the parentheses around `(I)` are just ignored. `select distinct` works across **the entire row** (i.e. all parts of each row are considered).

Comment: Ok I got it. So I tested with distinct I, O but It has same result.
1 is slower than 2. Can I know what's the difference of that?

Comment: I have no way of reproducing your specific issue. Perhaps 2 is benefiting from cache that 1 provided? Try running each of those queries with no cache `select distinct SQL_NO_CACHE` run 2 before 1 (a few times) then run 1 a few times, repeat. Record timing. Compare averages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query 1 has *two* temporaries (though it does not say so):  One for the subquery, one for `DISTINCT`.  Hence Query 1 is slower.

Another thing to note:  `Using filesort, Using temporary` usually shows up on the *first* row of `EXPLAIN`, even if it really applies to some other row.

For more details in `EXPLAIN`, use `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`